# Ruby method to reverse string input

Tags: ruby, string, reverse

I don't get why reversed_string=string[i] + reversed_string puts the last char first. It seems that string[i] would index the first char and not the last. So if the string was "abc" index 0 would be 'a' and not 'c'. Could someone please explain how ruby gets 'c' from index 0? And then, of course, 'b' from index 1? Etc, etc.

> Write a method that will take a string as input, and return a new string with the same letters in reverse order.
>
> Difficulty: easy.

```
def reverse(string)
  reversed_string = ""

  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    reversed_string = string[i] + reversed_string

    i += 1
  end

  return reversed_string
end
puts("reverse(\"abc\") == \"cba\": #{reverse("abc") == "cba"}")
puts("reverse(\"a\") == \"a\": #{reverse("a") == "a"}")
puts("reverse(\"\") == \"\": #{reverse("") == ""}")
```

Comment: "abcdefg".reverse! => "gfedcba"

Comment: @scottxu I think this question is intended to practice programming by writing a method that reverses a string.

Answer (score 5):

```
reversed_string = string[i] + reversed_string
```

For example, if `string` is `"abc"`, `string[0]` is indeed `"a"`, but here it's being put in the **beginning** of `reversed_string`, not the end. `reversed_string` is added up in each iteration as:

```
"a" + ""     #string[0] + ""  => "a"
"b" + "a"    #string[1] + "a" => "ba"
"c" + "ba"   #string[2] + "ba"=> "cba"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't use Ruby Class String's built in *Reverse* method, you could try the following

```
def reverse_string(string)
  new_string = []
  i = string.length-1
  while i >= 0
    new_string.push(string[i])
    i -= 1
  end
  new_string.join
end
```

This will create a new string object, but it will reverse the string without using any built-in methods.

Comment: You are using built in methods.  `push` and `length` for example.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, there is a method [String#reverse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-reverse) to reverse a string.  I understand you are not to use that method, but instead write your own, where the method's argument is the string to be reversed.  Others will suggest ways you might do that.

As you are new to Ruby, I thought it might be instructive to show you how you could write a new method for the `String` class, say, `String#my_reverse`, that behaves exactly the same as `String#reverse`. Then for the string `"three blind mice"`, we would have:

```
"three blind mice".reverse    #=> "ecim dnilb eerht"
"three blind mice".my_reverse #=> "ecim dnilb eerht"
```

To create a method without arguments for the String class, we normally do it like this:

```
class String
  def my_method
    ...
  end
end
```

We invoke `my_method` by *sending* it a receiver that is an instance of the `String` class. For example, if write:

```
"three blind mice".my_method
```

we are sending the method `String#my_method` to the receiver `"three blind mice"`. Within the definition of the method, the receiver is referred to as `self`. Here `self` would be `"three blind mice"`.  Similarly, just as the second character (at offset 1) of that string is `"three blind mice"[1] #=> "h"`, `self[1] #=> "h"`. We can check that:

```
class String
  def my_method
    puts "I is '#{self}'"
    (0...self.size).each { |i| puts self[i] }
  end
end

"three blind mice".my_method
```

would print:

```
I is 'three blind mice'
t
h
r
e
e

b
...
c
e
```

The method `my_reverse` is almost the same:

```
class String
  def my_reverse
    sz = self.size
    str = ''
    (0...sz).each { |i| str << self[sz-1-i] }
    str
  end
end

"three blind mice".my_reverse
  #=> "ecim dnilb eerht"
```

You can think of `self` as a variable whose value is the receiver, but unlike a variable, you cannot reassign self to a different object.  For example, we can write `x = 1; x = 'cat'`, but we cannot write `self = 'cat'`. As we have already seen, however, we can change the references self makes to other objects, such as `self[1] = 'r'`.